# Align middle text string inside the button

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I'm making some custom control for a small project. I have created a TP1CustomFlatButton like this:

[image: Image for TP1CustomFlatButton]

It was easy for me if I added a label with text to bottom of my TP1CustomFlatButton. I didn't want to handle events for that label so I used event onPaint to draw the text. I followed the turtorial of Microsoft and I got the custom flat button like the picture I attached. What I'm trying to get is to make the text align center at the bottom of my TP1CustomFlatButton.

This is my code for TP1CustomFlatButton:

```
// constructor
public TP1CustomFlatButton()
{
    this.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
    this.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
    this.BackColor = Color.MediumSeaGreen;
    this.ForeColor = Color.White;
    this.Text = "TP1CustomButton";
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
{
    pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.BackColor), new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height));
    TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.Bottom;

    //render text
    TextRenderer.DrawText(pevent.Graphics, this.Text, this.Font, new Point((int)(this.Width - Text.Length)/2,this.Height), this.ForeColor, flags);

    //draw image
    Image img = this.BackgroundImage;

    //create rectangle to display image
    Rectangle imgRec = new Rectangle(this.Width - 32 /3, this.Height - 32/ 3, 32, 32);
    if(img!=null)
        pevent.Graphics.DrawImage(img, imgRec);
}
```

I'm really confused with the coordinate X and Y. As you can see the code I tried to make the "SETTINGS" text string to align center at bottom of my TP1CustomFlatButton. I spent 5 hours to read more information about coordinate and location of controls in Windows Form. But now I'm really tired.

Hope someone can give me any advice or any solution for my custom control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `MeasureString()`method in order to calculate the middle.

also see the changes i have madein order to find the middle (calculated in `drawPoint` field).

see my example based on your code:

```
public TP1CustomFlatButton()
{
    this.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
    this.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
    this.BackColor = Color.MediumSeaGreen;
    this.ForeColor = Color.White;
    this.Text = "middle";
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
{
    pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.BackColor), new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height));
    TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.Bottom;

    //render text
    String drawString = this.Text;
    SizeF size = pevent.Graphics.MeasureString(drawString, this.Font);
    Point drawPoint = new Point((int)this.Size.Width / 2 - (int)size.Width / 2,this.Height);
    TextRenderer.DrawText(pevent.Graphics, this.Text, this.Font, drawPoint, this.ForeColor, flags);

    //draw image
    Image img = this.BackgroundImage;

    //create rectangle to display image
    Rectangle imgRec = new Rectangle(this.Width - 32 / 3, this.Height - 32 / 3, 32, 32);

    if (img != null)
        pevent.Graphics.DrawImage(img, imgRec);

}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved a bunch of time for me. Have a nice day =)

Comment: glad i could help (-:

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing the TextFormatFlags as below:

TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.Bottom | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter;

Also, checkout this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textformatflags(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I did what you said and nothing happened.